# (CORS error) Can't send POST request (OPTIONS gets denied) with Angular to ASP.net REST services

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, rest, http, http-headers

So, when I try sending POST request it doesn't succeed. Chrome prompts me with this error:

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:49475/api/Kpi/new (anonymous function) @ angular.js:10661sendReq @ angular.js:10480serverRequest @ angular.js:10187processQueue @ angular.js:14634(anonymous function) @ angular.js:14650Scope.$eval @ angular.js:15878Scope.$digest @ angular.js:15689Scope.$apply @ angular.js:15986(anonymous function) @ angular.js:23376n.event.dispatch @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3r.handle @ jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3

Index.html:1 XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:49475/api/MYLINK. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 405
```

I highly doubt my request is the problem, but it looks like this:

```
return $http.post(apiAddress + 'mylink', dataObj)
            .then(function (response) {
                console.log("succeeded");
                return response.status;
            }, function (response) {
                console.log("failed");
                return response.status;
            });
```

I have installed CORS on my API part, server one, and enabled it in WebApiConfig:

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
config.EnableCors(cors);
```

I have also edited my Web.config file and enabled all of Access Controls variables with:

```
<httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
        <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept" />
      </customHeaders>
</httpProtocol>
```

My client side is running on localhost:57810 and the server one is on localhost:49475. I have been looking for this to work for nearly 6 hours now. I've tried every possible snippet and "solution" I could find online and it is unsuccessfull. I wouldn't have posted this question if it was...

I appreciate any answer I get...

EDIT: Post method works as expected, I have tested it with Postman. Now, sending OPTIONS request to the mentioned url (api/mylink) doesn't work.

It returns:

```
{"Message":"The requested resource does not support http method 'OPTIONS'."}
```

Comment: did you try putting 
`[EnableCors(origins: "*", headers: "*", methods: "*")]`
on your ApiController?

Comment: I just tried and unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: Please post the signature of the action method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the configs within WebApiConfig and Web.config answer got mixed up and didn't work together. I will find more time to learn why was this a problem, but in the meantime the working solution was to:

1. Erase all the data in Web.config between `<httpprotocol>` tags (4th snippet in my post)
2. In WebApiConfig, in EnableCorsAttribute initialization, sending `'*'` as first parameter didn't work, but typing explicitly: `'http://localhost:57810'` did work! This is a second snippet in my original post.

I have no idea why the second one obstructed my server. Maybe it's some sort of a bug, since documentation clearly says that `'*'` is a wildcard, or maybe some other configurations prevented it from working.

If someone can expand on the answer, be my guest.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. I might have a clue.

I guess its a problem in routing: web api can't find the action, and can't find an options hadler for it.

The default routing method in Asp.Net webapi is that it decides the action in controller based on the request method.
I tend to dislike this approach and change the WebApiConfig file from

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}"
```

to

```
routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Also, you might put `[RoutePrefix("api/AAA")]` on your controller and `[Route("BBB")]` on your actions. Also, put `[HttpPost]` on your action, so you've explicitly set everything.
Now your url becomes `/api/AAA/BBB`
Please give it a try, test it in your server domain (port) and make sure your routing is working as expected. Then proceed to test it in the client domain(port).

Please tell me if it's gonna work

Comment: Due to internet problems I couldn't access SO earlier. I appreciate your answer, but the routes nor explicitly setting anything didn't work. I will answer my own question with the working solution. Thank you for trying to help, anyway, it is much appreciated.